# Selecting columns from multiple matrices to form a well-conditioned matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given multiple matrices of the same size, is there a way to select one column from each matrix to form a well-conditioned matrix?

For example, given four 4-by-10 matrices *A, B, C, D* (real, positive, full-ranked), I would like to select one column from each matrix to form a new 4-by-4 matrix *E*, such that *E* is well-conditioned.

I know that there are algorithms to select well-conditioned columns from one single matrix, but I was wondering if there is any algorithm to efficiently solve this problem? Thank you!